# How to build kernel after modifying specific files?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, compiling, kernel-modules, tcp

I'm new in kernel development and I modified two kernel files for a research project. Now, I already know how to do a fresh building of the kernel source code and that is what I did. I'm asking if I need to re-compile the whole kernel or I can skip some parts and compile just what I need: is it possible? Thanks!

***General info***

- *Linux distro*: Ubuntu 20.04
- *Kernel version*: 5.4.231
- Modified files:`tcp.h` and `tcp_input.c`
- File location (tcp.h): /include/net/
- File location (tcp_input.c) /net/ipv4/

Comment: I would think that running `make` (I assume that's still how kernels are compiled, it's been literally decades since I've compiled one) would simply compile what has changed or what depends on what has changed? what do you observe when running make? does the subsequent compilation take the same amount of time?

Comment: `make` takes care of that. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: yes! it works exactly like that, I just needed to compile using make command and it builds only the modified parts.